# Issue using childNodes to process the childnodes javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make display none for all the child nodes of a div. It works well with getElementsByTagname('*')

My Markup

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id"child2">
        <div id="inner-child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to manipulate the display property of only the child1, child2.

```
      function hideAllChildren(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("container");
        var children = elem.childNodes;
        alert("children " + children.length)
        for (i=0; i < children.length ;i++)
        {
        children[i].style.display="none";// Error - children[i].style undefined
        }

      }
```

Can you figureout what the issue could be ?

Comment: This should be working. The problem I see is that you're not declaring 'i'. Therefore, children[i] doesn't show anything. Use `var length = children.length; for (var i=0; i< length; i++)` (the 'length' variable is used for performance issue since you're not calculating children.length at every iteration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all the child nodes are elements, some are text nodes in some browsers and text nodes don't have a style property. Trying to access a property of a non-existant property throws an error.

Either test the node type or that the node has a (non-falsey value for its) style property first:

```
  if (children[i].style) {
    children[i].style.display="none";
  }
```

However, you may find it much better to use a class and appropriate CSS rule and just add it to the parent element.

e.g.

```
<style type="text/css">

.hideAll * {
  display: none;
}

</style>

</script type="text/javascript">

<button onclick="
  document.getElementById('d0').className = 'hideAll';
">Hide all</button>
<button onclick="
  document.getElementById('d0').className = '';
">Show all</button>

<div id="d0">Here is the div
  <ul>
    <li class="item">apple
    <li class="item">orange
    <li class="item">banana
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to hide all the child nodes.

Where you can hide the parent and all the child will automatically hide.

So it will be simply:

```
function hideAllChildren(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("container");
  //alert("children " + children.length)
  elem.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="container">container
    <div id="child1">child1</div>
    <div id"child2">Child 2
        <div id="inner-child">inner-child</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="clickme">Click me</div>
```

/// java script

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  hideAllChildren();
});

    function hideAllChildren(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("container");
        var children = elem.childNodes;
        alert("children " + children.length)
            $('#container').hide();      

      }
```